# Ms Access - Data type mismatch error when doing sum of few columns that will contain text symbols

Tags: ms-access

I'm working on a simple RDBMS project. My database contains work hours per day of each employee. I have to calculate work hours of complete month. It is not a problem. But I have a problem, here it goes, each workday field contains either number of work hours or it may contain text such as if the employee was absent (symbol "A") for a particular day or it may contain symbol ("H") for holiday etc. Now my task is to calculate the 30 day work hours and exclude any symbol. But obviously the approach I am using will get me "Data Type Mismatch Error." So any body got any solution or any suggestion please. Thanks in advance!

I tried to use sum formula with NZ function, it doesn't work. Also tried Query with the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Val`:

```
TrueHours: Val(Nz([YourHourTextFieldName]))
```

That will return 0 (zero) for non-numeric entries, and that allows you to sum the values.

Comment: It doesn't work. I used `=Sum(Val([Day1])+Val([Day2]))`

Comment: Then you have _Null_ values. Ignore those with _Nz_ as shown.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Initially I used your idea actually. But the one that worked for me is this one, =Sum(IIf(Nz([Day1],0),0)+IIf(Nz([Day2],0),0))